# Angular - Running ng serve ui-app-1 Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined

Tags: angular-cli

I am tasked to set up our Angular app to run with ng serve to utilize breakpoints in vscode and other features for trouble shooting code. I was able to get it to finally work but I have to run ng serve ui-app-1 which is in my angular.json but I just want to run the app as normal as possible in full. Please let me know if you need to see other files:

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ui-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {}, 
      "root": "projects/ui-app",
        "sourceRoot": "projects/ui-app/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../../wwwroots/SITESecured/ECDT/ui",
            "deployUrl": "/ECDT/ui/",
            "index": "projects/ui-app/src/angular_bundle_imports.forminc",
            "main": "projects/ui-app/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/ui-app/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/ui-app/tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "projects/ui-app/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/styles.css",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/fonts.css",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/responsive.css",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/utility.scss",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/sidebar-open.scss",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/input-group.scss",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/IE.css",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/Firefox.css",
              "projects/ui-app/src/app/styles/site.css",
              "../../wwwroots/SITESecured/FontAwesomePro/6.1.1-web/css/all.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/ui-app/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/ui-app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "7mb",
                  "maximumError": "15mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "15kb",
                  "maximumError": "20kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ECDT:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ECDT:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ECDT:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/ui-app/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/ui-app/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/ui-app/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/ui-app/karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "projects/ui-app/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
              "./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/styles.css",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/fonts.css",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/responsive.css",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/utility.scss",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/sidebar-open.scss",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/input-group.scss",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/IE.css",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets/css/Firefox.css",
              "projects/ui-app/src/app/styles/site.css",
              "../../wwwroots/SITESecured/FontAwesomePro/6.1.1-web/css/all.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/ui-app/tsconfig.app.json",
              "projects/ui-app/tsconfig.spec.json",
              "projects/ui-app/e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "projects/ui-app/e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ECDT:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ECDT:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "interfaces-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "projects/interfaces-app",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/interfaces-app/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../../wwwroots/SITESecured/ECDT/interfaces",
            "deployUrl": "/ECDT/interfaces/",
            "index": "projects/interfaces-app/angular_bundle_interfaces_imports.forminc",
            "main": "projects/interfaces-app/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/interfaces-app/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/interfaces-app/tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "projects/interfaces-app/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/interfaces-app/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/interfaces-app/src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/interfaces-app/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/interfaces-app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "8kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "interfaces-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "interfaces-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "interfaces-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/interfaces-app/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/interfaces-app/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/interfaces-app/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/interfaces-app/karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "projects/interfaces-app/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/interfaces-app/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/interfaces-app/src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/interfaces-app/tsconfig.app.json",
              "projects/interfaces-app/tsconfig.spec.json",
              "projects/interfaces-app/e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "projects/interfaces-app/e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "interfaces-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "interfaces-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ui-app-1": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "projects/ui-app",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/ui-app/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ui-app",
            "index": "projects/ui-app/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/ui-app/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/ui-app/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/ui-app/tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "projects/ui-app/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/ui-app/src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/ui-app/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/ui-app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "8kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ui-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ui-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ui-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/ui-app/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/ui-app/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/ui-app/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/ui-app/karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "projects/ui-app/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/ui-app/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/ui-app/src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/ui-app/tsconfig.app.json",
              "projects/ui-app/tsconfig.spec.json",
              "projects/ui-app/e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "projects/ui-app/e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ui-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ui-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "framework": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/framework",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/framework/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/framework/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/framework/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/framework/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/framework/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/framework/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/framework/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/framework/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/framework/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ui-app"
}
```

Package.json:

```
{
    "name": "ecdt",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --configuration=local",
        "build": "ng build",
        "build-interfaces": "ng build interfaces-app",
        "watch-interfaces": "ng build interfaces-app --watch",
        "copyinterfacescripts": "copyfiles --flat ./../../wwwroots/SITESecured/ECDT/interfaces/angular_bundle_interfaces_imports.forminc ./../../../ec-production/itec/html",
        "copyscripts": "copyfiles --flat ./../../wwwroots/SITESecured/ECDT/ui/angular_bundle_imports.forminc ./../../../ec-production/itec/html",
        "watch": "ng build --watch",
        "prod": "ng build --prod --aot",
        "prod-interfaces": "ng build interfaces-app --prod --aot",
        "postbuild": "npm run copyscripts",
        "postbuild-interfaces": "npm run copyinterfacescripts",
        "postprod": "npm run copyscripts",
        "postprod-interfaces": "npm run copyinterfacescripts",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "full-build": "npm run prod && npm run prod-interfaces"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
        "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.0",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
        "@schematics/angular": "^9.0.4",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.9.0",
        "angular-input-masks": "^4.4.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "bootstrap-icons": "^1.5.0",
        "component": "^1.1.0",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "is-promise": "^4.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.3",
        "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.4",
        "ng2-completer": "3.0.3",
        "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
        "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
        "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.2",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
        "ngx-currency": "^2.5.3",
        "ngx-doc-viewer": "^1.4.0",
        "ngx-drag-drop": "^2.0.0",
        "ngx-mask": "^8.1.7",
        "ngx-moment": "^3.5.0",
        "ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
        "ngx-typeahead": "^6.2.1",
        "ngx-xml2json": "^1.0.2",
        "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
        "save": "^2.4.0",
        "simplebar-angular": "^2.1.0",
        "stream": "0.0.2",
        "timers": "^0.1.1",
        "tslib": "^2.3.1",
        "updated": "^1.3.0",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2",
        "xml2js": "^0.4.23",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.24",
        "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.901.0",
        "@angular/cli": "8.3.22",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.14",
        "@angular/language-service": "8.2.14",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "^4.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "ng-packagr": "^9.0.0",
        "ng2-smart-table": "1.5.0",
        "ngx-datatable": "^1.0.3",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "~3.5.3"
    }
}
```

Intent:
A better title (IMHO) would be "Create Angular2 Login Page." This page should

ask for username and password, invoke the API

{{BaseUrl}}/AjaxJson/WebPageData/api/ValidateUser?USER_NAME={{login_username}}&PASSWORD={{login_password}}

[I will get you a sample of the JSON returned by validate_user] the return value will include a SessionID

Angular should use the sessionID to add cookie EC-SESSION to all requests from the browser

Upon success, the user will be forwarded/routed to the Whiteboard

The goal in this task or a Part II task is to be able to run the ECDT app using ng serve

Sample Api:

```
{
    "session": {
        "status": "OK",
        "status_message": "",
        "server": "LOCALHOST",
        "handler": "LOCAL-ITS-ITEC",
        "handler_instance": "001",
        "session_id": "16M4MRBM4H",
        "timezone_offset": "0",
        "impostor": "N",
        "is_admin": "1",
        "company_id": "754U3EFYK",
        "company_name": "Support",
        "THO_type": "",
        "company_created": "",
        "is_FUND": "true",
        "FUND_FSE_level": ""
    },
    "response": {
        "AuthorizationToken": "16M4MRBM4H",
        "AuthorizationTokenHash": "eAdsgqnf6AJ8YQndI/HODqQ=",
        "get_scw_url": "GetSCW?AuthorizationToken=16M4MRBM4H&AuthorizationTokenHash=eAdsgqnf6AJ8YQndI/HODqQ="
    }
}
```

Main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

import { ApplicationConfiguration } from '../../framework/src/lib/ApplicationConfiguration';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

declare var config: ApplicationConfiguration;
const providers = [{ provide: ApplicationConfiguration, useValue: config }];
platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: The end goal is to really just run ng serve and the app is set up to know what to do. I also created a page in angular for login since our current login page is done in angularJS.

The new login page had the intent to be a developer login

Comment: Editing the main.ts removes the error:
debugger;
var config: any;
config = ApplicationConfiguration;
const providers = [{ provide: ApplicationConfiguration, useValue: config }];
platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

But adds a new one:
Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.